# JQuery Else if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hi Im new to JQuery and Statements and I can't seem to get my code to work I'm pretty sure its something minor that is the error but I cant see to find what the problem is exactly here is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 400) {
        $('.BOX').animate({
            marginLeft: 500,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
        $('.BOX').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance if you can point me in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/86/  - Scrolltop >400 plays animations what I am trying to do is Reverse the animation when its less than 400 back to 0 left.

Comment: You're starting an animation on a `scroll` event, which means it's going to keep clobbering itself with every new invocation as the scrolling happens.

Comment: Can you give us some insight as to what the problem is? Some console error output, anything helps. We can't help you if you don't supply us with sufficient information.

Comment: try to check the .BOX margin and if it is animated like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/88/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the scroll event handler gets called over and over as the window is scrolled, so the animation gets started over and over. Those animations queue up, so by the time you scroll far enough for it to animate in the other direction, it is going to be a long time before you see it animate that way, and it may never because of an overflow.

You need to stop the animation before restarting it:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 400) {
        $('.BOX').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: 500,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
        $('.BOX').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5q6c0acm/)

Answer (score -1):

What exactly is `$(this)` referring to?

Try this instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 400) {
        $('.BOX').animate({
            marginLeft: 500,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 400) {
        $('.BOX').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginRight: 0,
            display: 'toggle'
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Also, you have quite a negative response on this question already. Try and help us to help you. If you say you're getting an error, it might help to say exactly what that error is. Other wise, we're just second guessing.

Comment: `this` here refers to the `window` object.